# Storing number list individually into 2-D Array in C++

Tags: visual-c++

Alright so I know how to store numbers into the array but I'm writing a Sudoku program and I need to read and store from an input file. The file will have a half finished Sudoku board and yeah I just have to do some things with it. My issue is that the numbers on the board aren't separated with spaces, like 123456789, and I need to read each number individually to store each one in a different position in the array. However, cin will just get the whole group, whereas cin.get() will give me the ASCII value...so I'm a little confused on how to get them individually stored. Maybe its an obvious answer that I'm just not seeing, I don't know. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for the reply Nick. I've got a little function to fill the 2-D Array from the input file. Here it is:

for ( i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
    {

```
    for ( j = 0; j < COLS ; j++ )
        {
             in.get(getData);
             data = getData - '0';
            myArray[i][j] = data;
        }


}
```

I  added the getData - '0' part that you recommended and it seems to work except that I'm getting this as output.

1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
-38|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
9|-38|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
8|9|-38|1|2|3|4|5|6|
7|8|9|-38|1|2|3|4|5|
6|7|8|9|-38|1|2|3|4|
5|6|7|8|9|-38|1|2|3|
4|5|6|7|8|9|-38|1|2|
3|4|5|6|7|8|9|-38|1|

The input file right now is just 9X9 rows and columns of '123456789' so it should just output that. Not sure where the -38 is coming from?
The code that displays it is virtually the same as the one that fills it just different functions right now. Any idea? Meanwhile, I'll be tinkering.

Ok nevermind that, I got that it was reading the endline and throwing things out of wack. I just put a little cin.get(temp) in there to read the endline and continue on. Hope that's the correct way of going about things.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
char c;

while(cin.get(c))
{ 
    if(!std::isdigit(c))
    { 
        /* not a digit - do whatever you want here */
    }

    int digit = c - '0';

    /* now digit contains the integer value of the digit in 'c' and you
     * can use it as needed. Let's call a function called dsw:
     */
    dsw(digit);
}
```